# Linker library error in visual studio

Tags: c++, linker, linker-errors

Running visual studio 2010 writing an openGL program in C++

I'm getting this error, and can't for the life of me figure out why

```
fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'Image_Loading/nvImage.lib'
```

The file is in the correct place, and nvImage.lib is present in the additional dependencies of the linker, any ideas??

Comment: The file is in the folder Image_Loading, not sure what you mean by reading the file but it can be opened in VS (it's not corrupted)

Comment: @user195257, that's what he meant.  He was checking read permissions.

Answer (score 1):

The folder "Image_Loading" is probably not in your library search path. Include files has a different search path, so even if its find the includes, the folder might be missing from the libary search path.

you should either add the folder to the LIB enviromental variable, or add /LIBPATH:*folder* to the command line of the linker.

Comment: Thank you, im pretty new to VS, how do i go about doin this??

Comment: 1. right click your project -> properties.
2. go to linker -> input.
3. in "additional dependencies" write the name of the lib: "nvImage.lib".
4. go to general.
5. add to "additional dependencies directories" the directory of the lib.
6. compile.